# Alternatives ou meilleure traduction pour le mot blog

Tags: traduction, anglicismes

Existe-t-il une meilleure traduction française pour "blog"? Je vois le mot existe dans le Larousse, mais j'aurais aimé un mot différent de l'anglais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'Académie française n'a a ma connaissance pas proposé de traduction du mot anglais *blog*, et consent à l'utiliser (mention des blogs de [Jean Métellus](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/jean-metellus), d'[Amin Maalouf](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/reception-de-m-amin-maalouf-f29)).

Le terme *blogue* est retenu par la [Comission générale de terminologie et néologie Française](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000029461191), mais même dans les publications gouvernementales, en France, *blog* est de loin le terme le plus courant.

L'[Office québecois de la langue française](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370242) préconise quant à lui une francisation de l'orthographe : *blogue*. Il accepte également *carnet Web*¹ et *cybercarnet*. Une recherche Google montre que [*blogue*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22blogue%22+site%3Aca) (≈8M pages) écrase [*carnet Web*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22carnet+Web%22+site%3Aca) (≈5k) et [*cybercarnet*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22cybercarnet%22+site%3Aca) (≈2k).

Il n'y a donc pas lieu de chercher plus loin que *blogue*. Même *blog* ne dépare pas particulièrement en français : il n'est pas rare de prononcer la dernière consonne d'un mot d'une syllabe ; *blog* rime avec *grog* (que je n'ai jamais vu proposer d'écrire *<s>*grogue*</s>) et suivrait *joug* (où la prononciation du `g` est optionnelle).

¹  <sub>[Web](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075076) est considéré comme acceptable par l'OQLF.</sub>

Comment: Pour _grog_ ouais bien intéressant ; de l'angl. _grogram_ qui est un emprûnt au français _gros-grain_ pour le _tissu côtélé_ (DHLF/Etymonline). Dans ce sens là le parcours est peut-être plus proche d'un truc comme la(qc) _toast_ de la _tostee_ avec double réemprûnt vers le français... on accepte bien plus facilement ?

Comment: @Legomononc'bléd'Ingres merci pour ces précisions. Il faut quand même noter que le mot grog a 150 (200 ?) ans en français, où l'on francisait (nettement ?) moins. Bug a lui dû subir quelques variations, du genre bogue !

Answer (score 0):

- Blogue
- Carnet Web
- Cybercarnet
- Journal Web
- Cyberjournal
- Joueb
- Jourel

Answer (score 0):

Pour rester dans le style du Blog composé de web et log : **Écritoile**

Comment: C'est joli mais je n'aurais certainement pas compris sans contexte.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est le cas général pour les néologismes, ils sont plus facilement interprétés en contexte...